# Two ways to get option selected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried two ways to get option selected values

1. `$(".card-vaild-month option:selected").val()`
2. `$(".card-vaild-month option:selected").text()`

and my option is generated by javascript,
when I use method #1 can't get value normally, but #2 can get value normally.

however, if my option is not generated by javascript (write on html directly )
Both of these methods are feasible

What is the difference of these two methods?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you include the javascipt you use to add the option when you use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(".card-vaild-month option:selected").val()`  returns the value mentioned in `value` attribute as in `<option value=<THISVALUE>` which is selected of course

and

`$(".card-vaild-month option:selected").text()` returns the text mentioned inside the tags as `<option>THISVALUE</option>`

Check the snippet below for the difference

```js
document.write("<br>val()="+$(".card-vaild-month option:selected").val());


document.write("<br>text()="+$(".card-vaild-month option:selected").text());
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<select class="card-vaild-month">
  <option value="0">zero</option>
  <option value="1" selected>one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should get the value of the select menu, not the option. In you case

```
$('.card-valid-month').val();
```

I added a little example below

```js
alert($('.input-select').val());

$('.input-select').on('change',function(){
 alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="input-select">
  <option value="0">0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```